# how do I perform a case-insensitive search in a Postgres 9.4 JSONB column?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

i'm using this query to look for data in a table where `profile` is a `JSONB` column
and it works but only if the name is exactly that

```
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "profile" @> '{"name":"Super User"}'
```

is it possible to have more flexibility like case insensitivity, wildcards and so on ?

Something like `"Super%"` or `"super user"`

Comment: To do that we'd need something like a json query language. There's nothing like that built-in, but some folks are working on a json query language extension. I can't find references right now, but it was discussed at PGConf EU 2014 in Madrid; maybe look at the conference session list.

Comment: are you referring to https://github.com/akorotkov/jsquery ? i'll try that

Comment: Yep, that's the one. It looked quite interesting. I don't know how stable/mature/documented/etc it is though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE (profile #>> '{name}') ILIKE 'super %'
```

I don't know if this is performing well enough but it works.
Probably it's wise to add an index to it.

Comment: What sort of index makes sense in this situation?

I understood GIN as only speeding up containment/existence queries on keys

Comment: Awesome dude! This worked like a charm for me! For anyone else who is also getting stuck at nested object traversing, just use: `profile #>> '{fullname, firstname,...}'`. Here, your object will be like: `{fullname: {firstname: 'abc'}}`