# Searching jsonb array in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to search a JSONB object in PostgreSQL 9.4. My question is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681163/how-do-i-perform-a-case-insensitive-search-in-a-postgres-9-4-jsonb-column).

However my data structure is slightly different which is causing me problems. My data structure is like:

```
[
    {"id":1, "msg":"testing"}
    {"id":2, "msg":"tested"}
    {"id":3, "msg":"nothing"}
]
```

and I want to search for matching objects in that array by msg (RegEx, LIKE, =, etc). To be more specific, I want all rows in the table where the JSONB field has an object with a "msg" that matches my request.

The following shows a structure similar to what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 
        '[{"id":1,"msg":"testing"},{"id":2,"msg":"tested"},{"id":3,"msg":"nothing"}]'::jsonb as data) 
    as jsonbexample;
```

This shows an attempt to implement the answer to the above link, but does not work (returns 0 rows):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 
        '[{"id":1,"msg":"testing"},{"id":2,"msg":"tested"},{"id":3,"msg":"nothing"}]'::jsonb as data) 
    as jsonbexample 
WHERE 
    (data #>> '{msg}') LIKE '%est%';
```

Can anyone explain how to search through a JSONB array? In the above example I would like to find any row in the table whose "data" JSONB field contains an object where "msg" matches something (for example, LIKE '%est%').

---

### Update

This code creates a new type (needed for later):

```
CREATE TYPE AlertLine AS (id INTEGER, msg TEXT);
```

Then you can use this to rip apart the column with JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET(
        null::AlertLine, 
        (SELECT '[{"id":1,"msg":"testing"},
                  {"id":2,"msg":"tested"},
                  {"id":3,"msg":"nothing"}]'::jsonb 
         as data
        )
    ) as jsonbex;
```

Outputs:

```
 id |   msg   
----+---------
  1 | testing
  2 | tested
  3 | nothing
```

And putting in the constraints:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET(
        null::AlertLine, 
        (SELECT '[{"id":1,"msg":"testing"},
                  {"id":2,"msg":"tested"},
                  {"id":3,"msg":"nothing"}]'::jsonb 
         as data)
        ) as jsonbex 
WHERE 
    msg LIKE '%est%';
```

Outputs:

```
id |   msg   
---+---------
 1 | testing
 2 | tested
```

So the part of the question still remaining is how to put this as a clause in another query.

So, if the output of the above code = x, how would I ask:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x > (0 rows);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 
        '[{"id":1,"msg":"testing"},{"id":2,"msg":"tested"},{"id":3,"msg":"nothing"}]'::jsonb as data) 
    as jsonbexample 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) as j(data) WHERE (data#>> '{msg}') LIKE '%est%');
```

To query table as mentioned in comment below:

```
SELECT * FROM atable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM jsonb_array_elements(columnx) as j(data) WHERE (data#>> '{msg}') LIKE '%est%');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It is indeed very useful and indeed works. However I'm having trouble adapting this for my purpose (as in my original question). If I need to, say, SELECT * FROM atable WHERE <columnx contains an object where msg LIKE '%est%'>, how would I use the above code?

Comment: @browner87 I've updated answer. Please comment if further explanation needed.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz Oooh Thank You! I had a problem which I coudn't address and this question & answer made it so simple! Thanks browner too.